# Display pictures of sd card in GridView

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin

I am trying to display some pictures from the sd storage in GridView in a Xamarin.Android app.

The only documentation I've found is this: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/selecting_a_gallery_image

But it only works for one image, opening two or more pictures gives me an `Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError`

on this row:

```
imageView.SetImageURI (bitmapList [position]);
```

Found some Android answers here on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/823966/511299

Translated to C#:

```
public static Bitmap DecodeFile (String s)
{
    try
    {
        s = s.Replace ("file://", "");
        //Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
        o.InJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (new System.IO.FileStream (s, System.IO.FileMode.Open), null, o);

        //The new size we want to scale to
        int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.OutWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE && o.OutHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
        {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        //Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
        o2.InSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (new System.IO.FileStream (s, System.IO.FileMode.Open), null, o2);

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

This gives me an

```
System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path  storage/sdcard0/Pictures/MyAppPhotos/44cdbcf0-a488-40b8-98a9-79f3dc8d9deb.jpg
```

on the line of

```
return BitmapFactory.DecodeStream (new System.IO.FileStream (s, System.IO.FileMode.Open), null, o2);
```

Is it possible I access the file twice?

Or is it perhaps because I use `FileStream` instead of `FileInputStream`. Trying to use `BitmapFactory.DecodeStream` requires a `System.IO.Stream` as parameter, opposed to the example requiring a string :(

More detailed, here is the Android version of `decodeStream`:

```
public static Bitmap decodeStream (InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

while this is all I can find for Xamarin.Android:

```
public static Bitmap DecodeStream (System.IO.Stream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Used `BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(String path, BitmapFactory.Options opts)` instead!